# Implementing a like button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfobject

I'm having trouble implementing a working like button in a table cell, using Parse as the backend. There is a button in the tablecell, which is called using a sender/tag. Here's the code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeedCell";

FeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[FeedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
    PFObject *post = [postArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 cell.likeForYa.tag = indexPath.row;

[cell.likeForYa addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


}
```

In the sender void, here's the code:

```
-(void)aMethod:(id)sender {
UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"current Row=%d",senderButton.tag);

PFObject *tempObject = [postArray objectAtIndex:senderButton.tag];
NSLog(@"%@", tempObject.objectId);

//add the object ID for the cell we are liking to the array of liked items in the user class in parse
[[PFUser currentUser]addUniqueObject:tempObject.objectId forKey:@"liked"];
[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];


PFObject* like = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Like"];
[like setObject:[PFUser currentUser][@"username"] forKey:@"username"];
[like setObject:tempObject.objectId forKey:@"photo"];
[like saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Like"];
    [query whereKey:@"photo" equalTo:tempObject.objectId];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Number: %lu", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        //cell.lik.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)objects.count];
    }];
}];




 }
```

When the button is clicked, nothing is stores and the log for objects.count returns 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you willing to switch to PFQueryTableViewController? If so, I can help you implement like-button?

Comment: Sure. I would appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here you subclass with PFQueryTableViewController and your tableViewCell may look something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeedCell";

  FeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {

      cell = [[FeedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      UIButton *likeForYa = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [likeForYa setTag:CellLikeForYaTag];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:likeForYa];
      [likeForYa addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(aMethod:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  }

  UIButton * likeForYa = (UIButton*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:CellLikeForYaTag];

  // check if current user like the post and change like-button image accordingly
  if ([[object objectForKey:@"whoLiked"]containsObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {

     [likeForYa setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pressedLike.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  } else {

     [likeForYa setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unpressedLike.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  }

}
```

And here's the aMethod:

```
- (void)aMethod:(UIButton *)button{

    CGPoint hitPoint = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:hitIndex.row];

    // check if current user already liked the post
    if (![[object objectForKey:@"whoLiked"]containsObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {

        //add the object ID for the cell we are liking to the array of liked items in the user class in parse
        [[PFUser currentUser] addUniqueObject:object.objectId forKey:@"liked"];
        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];

        //add the user ID to the post that the user liked
        [object addUniqueObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"whoLiked"];
        [object saveInBackground];

    } else {

        //remove the object ID for the cell we are liking to the array of liked items in the user class in parse
        [[PFUser currentUser] removeObject:object.objectId forKey:@"liked"];
        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];

        //remove the user ID to the post that the user liked
        [object removeObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"whoLiked"];
        [object saveInBackground];

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: You're the very best. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you! I was wondering if you could tell me how to retrieve the like count with the new code!

Comment: Sure just creat a new question for that. I'll follow to answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Alway get aware of result that is throwing error or not.

```
PFObject* like = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Like"];
[like setObject:[PFUser currentUser][@"username"] forKey:@"username"];
[like setObject:tempObject.objectId forKey:@"photo"];
[like saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

    //1. Check isSuccess
    if (succeeded) {

            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Like"];
            [query whereKey:@"photo" equalTo:tempObject.objectId];
            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

                if (error == nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Number: %lu", (unsigned long)objects.count);
                    //cell.lik.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)objects.count];
                }

            }];

    }

}];
```

Another thing is make sure your DataTable/Class/Object Structure in the parse.com is matches the name and also type what you are passing here.

**Just like**

"Like" class that have field "username" and it's type String. And "photo" that have type same like (tempObject.objectId).

Comment: Hello. Thanks for you reply. Nothing happens still.

Comment: that means your first call for saving Like is success.

Comment: and when you are fetching that saved object is nil. Right?

Comment: The like wasn't saved :( The filled things you saw were from another app I was worked off of. My own button does nothing at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89441/discussion-between-chetan-prajapati-and-halesenchanted).